# error libssh2 development package not found

Tags: macos, qt

I have qt 5.9.1 on my mac and I get the following error

```
 libssh2 development package not found
```

I have libssh2 installed using brew. it is under /usr/local/lib/

I have setup my .PRO file as following

```
 PKGCONFIG += libssh2 libxml-2.0
```

I have searched for similar issues but neither of the solutions has helped.

any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
 11:15:34: Starting: "/Users/apatel/Qt/5.9.1/clang_64/bin/qmake" /Users/apatel/workspace/seafight.git/code/tools/rcon/RCON.pro -spec macx-clang CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=x86_64 CONFIG+=qml_debug
 Project ERROR: libssh2 development package not found
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure that `pkg-config` is actually up to date with:

```
brew upgrade pkg-config
brew update
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, then check if libssh2 installs a `libssh2.pc` file in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/. If not, you can't use pkg-config with it.

If there is a `libssh2.pc` in that directory, then pkg-config is not configured to search there. Add `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig` to the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable. You can do that in your `.bash_profile` file in your home directory, by adding this:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig"
```

Logout/login (or reboot) and then your project file should be able to find the library.

Update:

macOS nowadays clears the environment when launching GUI applications. I don't know why, but that's what Apple has decided is best for you. So the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable is being deleted. You need to either search for ways to make macOS not clear the environment, or you need to define appropriate `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` variables in your project's build settings (it has an "environment" section.)

Comment: this didn’t help. i get the same error in the qt creator

Comment: @Anand macOS clears the environment when launching GUI applications. I don't know why, but that's what Apple has decided. So the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` env variable is being deleted. You need to either search for ways to make macOS not clear the environment, or you need to define appropriate `PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` env vars in your project's build settings (it has an "environment" section.)

Comment: that didn’t help either. added PKG_CONFIG_PATH in the Build Environment section of project build settings. Btw this was already set to Use System Environment and
Set PKG_CONFIG_PATH to /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/pkgconfig

Comment: and the “clear system environment” check was not ticked

Comment: @Anand macOS clears the environment, not Creator. So you also need to change the existing `PATH` and prepend `/usr/local/bin:` to it.